# english-greek language in tccv document class

Tags: fonts, languages, document-classes

I am using `tccv` document class in order to create my cv in Greek. For this reason I mainly have two questions: (1) is it possible to print my name in Greek but leave "curriculum vitae" in English; (2) how can I change the fonts?

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{tccv}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\part{\selectlanguage{greek} Nicola Fontana} 

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}



\end{eventlist}
\end{dpcument}
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: I [here](http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/) you can find the document class

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) It depends. Best of luck!

Comment: How can I solve my 1st problem? '\setlanguage{greek}' command does not seem to work in that case

Comment: Please post a Minimum Working Example (MWE) i.e. a small document we can compile which to reproduce the problem. `\documentclass... \end{document}`. Right now, there is very little information in your question at all. Also, please state which engine you are using if your code does not make that obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have taken one of the examples in the ZIP file, changing just the name to one of a hero of Greek independence. I left the rest unchanged, for lack of knowledge of Greek.

You can change font, provided you use one that supports Greek, I used GFS Artemisia.

I also changed the nonsensical Zapf Chancery for “Curriculum Vitae”.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt]{tccv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Why on earth using Zapf Chancery? Whoever receives the
% CV will laugh at it.
\xpatchcmd{\part}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\part[\textlatin{Curriculum Vitae}]{Θεόδωρος Κολοκοτρώνης}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{July 2007 -- Present}
     {eNTiDi software, Travagliato}
     {Management and development}

...
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change the font of  and the color of "curriculum vitae"? I was thinking about the same color with the sections and zapfino lite-one font

Comment: If I use '\selectlanguage{}' for the address, the the output does not fit with the symbol in the box (actually, my address is lower than the respective symbol)